# Construct pairs of $n$-dimensional convex bodies with given ratios ($p$) of volumes

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics, convex-geometry, computational-geometry

Given a dimension $n$ and a number $p \in (0,1)$, to what extent is it possible (in what cases) to construct a convex set $A$--not a hypersphere--and a "snugly" inscribed ([InscribedFigure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_figure)) convex set $B$, such that
(Euclidean) volume(B)=$p$ volume(A)? What if $p$ is rational? ([pRational](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3786874/construct-certain-pairs-of-n-dimensional-convex-setshttps://))

Comment: Why not just use for $B$ a scaled down version of $A$?

Comment: Or why not slice $A$ with a hyperplane $H$ to reach $p$ times the volume of $A$ in the remainder? One could start with $H$ outside and move it parallel inward continuously until $p \, \textrm{vol}(A)$ is reached.

Comment: Joseph O'Rourke--that would surely do the trick (though not what I was envisioning). Perhaps I should exempt this possibility --to add a further challenge.

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "inscribed"?

Comment: Thanks for the comment--M. Winter. I did provide that link to the Wikipedia article "Inscribed Figure". Maybe, it's a little tricky. The term "snugly" seems to convey the concept. Perhaps, the relevant idea here is that any similarity transformation of B expanding it, without any translation of B, would yield points outside A.

Comment: To continue, perhaps the test should be that any vertex of B (though it may not have any) has to lie on the boundary of  A.