# If the volume-ratio of an inscribed convex set to the circumscribing convex set is rational, can anything of consequence be further deduced?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, convex-geometry, euclidean-geometry

Say, one has two $n$-dimensional convex sets $A$ and $B$, with $B$ being inscribed in the strictly larger set $A$. ($A$ and $B$ have at least one boundary point in common. $B$ “fits snugly” in $A$ [Inscribed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_figure).) Now, the ratio of the volume of $B$ to that of $A$ is a rational $\in (0,1)$.

Thus, the ratio is, in some sense, exceptional, since the rationals are countable, and the reals $\in (0,1)$, uncountable.

So, can anything further concerning the relation of $A$ and $B$ be drawn from this very general observation? (If so--though, unlikely, I surmise--how might the choice of geometry, Euclidean or otherwise, affect matters?)

Additionally, I would be interested in constructions in which $A$ is not a
hyperball.

Comment: You can produce many examples. Say $A$ is the unit disk in the plane. $D$ is the horizontal diameter. Take a continuous concave function $$f:[-1,1]\to[0,\infty),$$ such that $f(x)\leq \sqrt{1-x^2}$. Now, for $t\in (0,1]$, 
 we denote  by $B_t$ the convex region $$B_t:=\{ (x,y) ;\; x\in [0,1],\;y|\leq tf(x)\}.$$ Then $B_t$ is inscribed in $A$ and  $$\mathrm{area}(B_t)=2t\int_{-1}^1 f(x)\; dx. $$ By varying $t$ we can get  the ratio of the area be any arbitrarily small number rational. If you take $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ we can make this ratio be any rational number in $(0,1)$.

Comment: Thanks, Liviu Nicolaescu! Guess this doesn't readily extend to higher-dimensional  ($n>2$) convex sets.

Comment: Yes it  does.   In the space  with coordinates $(y,x)$,  $y\in\mathbb{R}$, $x=(x_1,\dotsc, x_n)\in \mathbb{R}^n$,  $A$ is the  closed unit ball in the $(y, x)$ space,   $D$ is the closed  ball of radius $1$ in the $x$-space. Choose $f:D\to[0,\infty)$ continuous and concave satisfying $f(x)\leq \sqrt{1-|x|^2} $ and $$ B_t=\{(y,x);\;\;x\in D,\;\; |y|\leq tf(x)\}. $$

Comment: Thanks again, L. N. Perhaps these comments of yours merit a little expansion into an answer, where a couple of examples of $f$ could be employed and illustrated. Also, is your example somewhat related to that in the comment of Joseph O'Rourke to my rather related query https://mathoverflow.net/questions/368908/construct-pairs-of-n-dimensional-convex-bodies-with-given-ratios-p-of-volu ? Further, perhaps I'll append a remark to my question here, asking if examples in which $A$ is not a hyperball can be given.